# Phaser 3 Typescript error Game not binding

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So far I've tried to simply start a Phaser 3 game using Typescript bindings. Below is my main.js entry point.

```
/**@type {import("../typings/phaser")} */
let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
};
let game = Phaser.Game(config);
```

I'm using what I believe to be the most up to date typescript definitions in the phaser.d.ts. However, when I load the game, I get the following error.

```
phaser.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at Object.initialize [as Game] (phaser.min.js:1)
    at Object.parcelRequire.src/main.js (main.js:7)
    at newRequire (main.1e43358e.js:49)
    at main.1e43358e.js:81
    at main.1e43358e.js:107
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Phaser.Game` is a contructor function, need to use the keyword `new`:

```
let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you so much!